# Using Cosmos SDK how to fix: failed to parse log level

Tags: sdk

can anyone help me out on why i see this error when running `gaiad version`

```
Error: failed to parse log level (main:info,state:info,statesync:info,*:error): Unknown Level String: 'main:info,state:info,statesync:info,*:error', defaulting to NoLevel
Usage:
  gaiad version [flags]

Flags:
  -h, --help            help for version
      --long            Print long version information
  -o, --output string   Output format (text|json) (default "text")

Global Flags:
      --home string         directory for config and data (default "/Users/highlander/.gaia")
      --log_format string   The logging format (json|plain) (default "plain")
      --log_level string    The logging level (trace|debug|info|warn|error|fatal|panic) (default "info")
      --trace               print out full stack trace on errors
```

Comment: Removing `~/.gaia` directory(default home directory of gaiad) might help you. DO NOT FORGET to make a backup of old directory if you need.